# Updating JSON values are not replacing with old values

Tags: android, json, database, sql-update

I have values in JSON format in server and getting these values then displaying into mobile app textview. I'm storing the values into local database then getting from it, but if i change any values in server JSON and the text view is not loading new values it always showing old values. How can i replace the table with new data everytime user check the JSON?

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  String CREATE_TABLE_BEACON = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BEACON + "("
                    + KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR,"+ KEY_UUID + " VARCHAR,"+ KEY_MAJOR_ID + " INTEGER,"+ KEY_MINOR_ID + " INTEGER,"+ KEY_TYPE + " VARCHAR,"+ KEY_ACTION + " VARCHAR)";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BEACON);

        }

      public long insertBeaconDetails(BeaconDetails beacondetailstore) 
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

             values.put(KEY_NAME,beacondetailstore.name);
             values.put(KEY_UUID,beacondetailstore.uuid);
             values.put(KEY_MAJOR_ID,beacondetailstore.major);
             values.put(KEY_MINOR_ID,beacondetailstore.minor);
           //  values.put(KEY_NOTIFICATION,beacondetailstore.notification);
             values.put(KEY_TYPE,beacondetailstore.type);    
            values.put(KEY_ACTION,beacondetailstore.action);    


             long rowId = db.replace(TABLE_BEACON, null, values);
             db.close();
             return rowId;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use update query and every time the user check new json  load your data from database into ur textview.

Like : 
         db.update( "TABLE_NAME",
                  values,
                   TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " = ?",
                    new String[] { OLD_VALUE_OF_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME });

then : 
     retreive the data from database and load it again into your textview